# How do I access a dictionary key in a context variable that gets passed from a ListView to a template?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I want to access a dictionary key in a context variable that gets passed from a `ListView` to a template.

Here is my `views.py` file:

```
class ListJobListingsView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'employers/list_joblistings.html'
    model = JobListing
    context_object_name = 'joblistings_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        object_list = JobListing.objects.filter(admin_approved=True).order_by('job_title')[:5]

        category = self.request.GET.get("category", None)
        job_title = self.request.GET.get("job_title", None)
        if category and not job_title:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter() #TODO: make the query based on foreign key
        if job_title and not category:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(name__contains=job_title)
        if job_title and category:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(name__contains=job_title) #TODO: make the query based on foreign key

        return object_list

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the category choice
        context['categories'] = Category_JobListing._meta.get_field("category").choices
        return context
```

Note how I have added the `context['categories']` to my context in the `get_context_data` method.

In my `list_joblistings.html` template, I have:

```
{% if joblistings_list %}
    <form method="get" action="{% url 'employers:list_joblistings' %}">
      <p>Filter by category:</p>
      <select name="category">
          {% for key, value in joblistings_list.categories.items %}
              <option value="{{ key }}"> {{ value }} </option>
          {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <p>Search by job title: <input type="text" name="job_title"/></p>
      <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit"/></p>
    </form>
    <p> joblistings_list.categories.items = {{ joblistings_list.categories.items }} </p>
    <p> joblistings_list = {{ joblistings_list }} </p>
    <ul>
    {% for joblisting in joblistings_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'employers:detail_joblisting' joblisting.id %}">{{ joblisting.job_title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No job listings are available at the moment.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Here, the expression `{{ joblistings_list }}` yields a list of job listings (as it should), but `{{ joblistings_list.categories.items }}` yields nothing! It's empty! This is strange because I populated it with choices in the `ListView`.

I ruled out the possibility of there being an error on the server side by checking what `Category_JobListing._meta.get_field("category").choices` returns. It does return all the choices (the thing I want).

**How do I fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added new variable in a context called `categories` so you can access its value through iterating `categories`

```
      {% for key, value in categories.items %}
           ....
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. It was actually just `categories`, not `categories.items`.